# Freeware program to convert big PDF eg 200MB PDF, to RTF, and compatible with Windows 7?

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, document-converter, rtf

Is there a freeware program to convert a big PDF (e.g. 200MB) PDF, to RTF, that is compatible with Windows 7?

Comment: By "free" do you mean "free of financial cost"?  If so, I added the word and tag `gratis` for you.  If not, please kindly edit to reflect your meaning.  Thanks!

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate yes I mean free of financial cost.  Freeware. I am not talking about open source. I'd have hoped the guy that eats stuff out his toes hadn't brainwashed people here but it seems he has!

Comment: If someone is eating stuff out of their toes, and isn't sharing with everyone, shame on them. ;)  I'm honestly not sure of your reference, but that's okay.  If you're disliking the term *"gratis"* vs. *"freeware"*, yes I don't love it either, but it seems to be clear once you get familiar with it.  And it translates better in some languages, which is always nice.

Comment: a workaround  I used, lacking a windows 7 program, was to make a digitalocean VPS eg ubuntu and do https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301318/how-to-ocr-a-pdf-file-and-get-the-text-stored-within-the-pdf

Answer (score 0):

From GUI apps, [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) can [convert](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html) PDFs to RTFs decently, but not perfectly - which is to be expected as conversion from PDF is usually more or less lossy. Earlier versions - `< 3.48` - work on Windows 7 from what I see, but might have worse support for conversion than current versions.

Other than that, I wouldn't expect wonders for system that has been out of maintenance for a while now.